# Remove row with matching string from dynamically appended json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I currently have 2 objects that I am appending from json file and each holding an array of objects, each having `title` and `total` properties.

```
if (key === 'Item1') {
value[key].forEach(function (val) {
var tbl1Row = "<tr " + (parseInt(val.Total) > 3 ? " class='colorgul'" : "") + (parseInt(val.Total) < 4 ? " class='colorgreen'" : "") + ">" + "<td>" + val.Title + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.Total + "</td>" + "</tr>"
table1Rows += tbl1Row;
 })
}
```

What I am trying to do is remove all off the rows if Title equals to "VIP"

With below code I am able to see it in the console.log()

```
if (key === 'Item1') {
var obj = value[key].filter(function (item) {
return item.Title === "VIP"
})[0];
```

I just don't how can I remove it from table.

Comment: Have you tried making the control inside your forEach function and if the title is VIP, not appending it to the table as row?

Comment: Yes it solved my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (key === 'Item1') {
    value[key].forEach(function (val) {
        if (val.Title != "VIP") {
            var tbl1Row = "<tr " + (parseInt(val.Total) > 3 ? " class='colorgul'" : "") + (parseInt(val.Total) < 4 ? " class='colorgreen'" : "") + ">" + "<td>" + val.Title + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.Total + "</td>" + "</tr>"
            table1Rows += tbl1Row;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Accept this answer if it solved your question, this way it may be more helpful for those who visit the question and look for an accepted answer later.